# Why we have to use dependency manager?

Tags: ios, cocoa, carthage

I am developing an app for IOS,and I have to use some framework.
as you know  Cocoa pods and Carthage are dependancy manager for iOS and mac OS
my question is "why we have to use dependancy manager?, instead of using dependancy manager just clone that project[was written by other programmer and can be used as framework] and drag and drop to your project ??"

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few things that you need to think about is:

1. Updating your dependencies when new versions came out.
2. Updating dependencies for multiple platforms.
3. Interdependent frameworks and different framework versions for dependant frameworks.

Basically, time that you will spend on maintaining dependancies for your project will grow as your project grows. Dependancy managers allow you to avoid all this unnecessary and boring work.
There are a lot of other reasons to use DM instead of just importing frameworks. More about you can find [here](http://nshipster.com/cocoapods/). And [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/cocoapods-good/).

Answer (score 1):

**Why Libraries are Your Friend**

> While you aren’t strictly required to use third-party libraries or
>   frameworks, they can definitely save you a lot of time and let you
>   focus on polishing your app instead of typing out countless lines of
>   code that you simply don’t need to write.
>
> You can use third-party frameworks and libraries without a dependency
>   manager too, and you can get hands-on tutorials about them right here
>   on this site. For example, there’s our Alamofire tutorial, and our
>   SwiftyJSON tutorial.
>
> Without a dependency manager, you simply add each library’s code to
>   your project manually. However, this approach has several
>   disadvantages:
>
> 1. Updating a library to a new version can be difficult, especially if several libraries must be updated together because one depends on
>      another.
> 2. Including a library in your project makes it tempting to make local changes to the code, making it harder to update to a newer version
>      later.
> 3. Determining the current versions of libraries used in your app can be hard to do, especially if you don’t proactively keep track of them.
> 4. Finding new libraries can be difficult without a central location to see all the available libraries.
> 5. CocoaPods helps you overcome all of these issues and more. It fetches library code, resolves dependencies between libraries, helps
>      you search for and discover new libraries, and even sets up the right
>      environment to build your project with minimum hassle.

**Courtesy** 
https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

Answer (score 1):

At some point you might want to use 3rd party code to get extra features or something, you can copy the source code but how you will update it in the future? keep coping it again!!

Also some of your 3rd party code might depend on other 3rd part code, and if you copied it twice, you will get duplicate symbols.

Dependency managers handle all this for you.

My advice is to use Carthage or submodules, but do not use CocoPods, anything that touches the project file is not a good practice with Apple.

Comment: yeah,Carthage is  much  better than CocoPods

Comment: Disagree with not using CocoaPods. It depends where to use what. Cocoapods is the most simple depency manager solution. Also I have no issues when using it.

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by most simple, Carthage does all that without affecting or updating any workspace/project file. It might be a preference issue but I am sure most engineers will prefer Carthage due to the less intrusive integration.